# How to copy data from Excel to Word doc through VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy data from excel file to a word file as a screenshot. But the issue is that the data pasted is very small. Is there any way to increase its size while copying or after pasting? Below is the code i have written. Thanks in advance.

```
    Range("A" & startRow & ":G" & endRow).Select
    Selection.Copy

    With WordApp
        .Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
            DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, Placement:=wdInLine
        .Selection.TypeParagraph

        .Selection.Orientation = wdTextOrientationVertical
    End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resize your shape after you've copied it as it is the last shape you built.

Here is the code you can add:

```
Dim oShape As Word.InlineShape
Dim i As Integer
i = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count
' set oShape to the LAST inlineshape
Set oShape = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(i)
    With oShape
' examples only - scale to 90%
        .ScaleHeight = 90
        .ScaleWidth = 90
        ' * * * etc etc etc * * * *
    End With
Set oShape = Nothing
```

And you can simplify your Excel code because you don't have to select before copying:

```
Range("A" & startRow & ":G" & endRow).Copy
```

is enough

Comment: +1 and especially since OP doensn't seem to care about answers to his questions...

Comment: Thanks Issun :). Actually, I wanted to know how we could resize a Shape... I found it though

Comment: Yeah, I never knew either so that's pretty neat. :)